# Displaying Image in ComboBox's selected item

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox, datatemplate

I have a custom template for my WPF windows ComboBoxes, which display items that inherit from ComboBoxItem that also have an Image property (so that my items can display both text and an image). Both the text and image display as expected in the ComboBox's popup menu for any given item, but I haven't been able to display an image in the currently selected item.

The ContentPresenter within the ComboBox template that displays the currently selected item has its Content property properly bound to {TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItem}, and its ContentTemplate is bound to the following static resource:

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="SelectionBoxItemTemplateTextAndImage" DataType="{x:Type SB:SBComboBoxItem}">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="20"/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Image Source="{Binding Image}"/>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding}"/>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
```

SBComboBoxItem is the custom control that inherits from ComboBox and contains an "Image" property properly registered as a DependencyProperty.

I have attempted alternative implementations of that DataTemplate, including using:

```
{Binding Path=Image, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}
```

as the image's source. That didn't work, even though the text still displays when i set the TextBlock's Text property to:

```
{Binding Path=Content, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}
```

I've played around and found numerous implementations that display the text, but the equivalents never work for the image. I don't understand why this doesn't work, as setting up the popup to display both images and text was a breeze.

Edit: Here's the added functionality to ComboBoxItem to handle the image, in case there's something I did wrong there:

```
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ImageProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Image", typeof(Image), typeof(SBComboBoxItem));
    public Image Image { get { return (Image)GetValue(ImageProperty); } set { SetValue(ImageProperty, value); } }
```

And here is where I have a ComboBox with the items added:

```
<ComboBox SelectedIndex="1">
    <SB:SBComboBoxItem Content="Text">
        <SB:SBComboBoxItem.Image>
            <Image Source="..\Images\Table.png"/>
        </SB:SBComboBoxItem.Image>
    </SB:SBComboBoxItem>
    <SB:SBComboBoxItem Content="MoreText">
        <SB:SBComboBoxItem.Image>
            <Image Source="..\Images\Euclidian.png"/>
        </SB:SBComboBoxItem.Image>
    </SB:SBComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>
```

Comment: This all seems fine. Did you check the path of your image? It should be something like `'pack://application:,,,/SomeAssebmly;component/Resources/SomeImage.JPG`

Comment: Creating a custom class just to display an image is not a good idea. A `DataTemplate` should do just fine. Also if you inherit from ComboBoxItem you would also need to inherit from ComboBox to make it create those custom items instead of normal ones, it's an unnecessary mess.

Comment: Willem - The physical path is fine. As I said before, the Image property of the item is set and the image displays next to the text in the dropdown popup.

Comment: H.B. - Not only is this incorrect, but it's also unhelpful. I am inheriting from ComboBoxItem because I'm extending its functionality beyond what it can support with it's base property set. And a custom control inherited from ComboBox is not necessary, as the handling of a new ComboBoxItem type can be done entirely in the combobox's templating.

Comment: @Nasai: use `@`-notation, you can read about that on meta somewhere, people do not get notified otherwise. What you do has nothing to do with templating, you just create the items manually (which is almost crime in itself), *in most cases* one binds the `ItemsSource` to some data collection, then you have no control over which container is created. Also adding an Image property hardly qualifies as extending functionality, unless it does something else that you have not shown my points still stand.

Comment: @Nasai: Maybe you will understand my point if you read the [data templating overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521.aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite the fact that I was using a DataTemplate to expose the underlying type of my selected combobox item through DataTemplate's DataType property, the SelectionBoxItem property of my ComboBox was apparently returning something that could not be cast as my custom ComboBoxItem. I don't know why this is, nor why it did not fire any runtime errors, but I found that by binding to ComboBox's SelectedItem property instead of SelectionBoxItem in the ContentPresenter allowed me to access user defined properties.

Answer (score 0):

Does the DataTemplate even work? As far I remember, any WPF element that can be rendered, wont use a DataTemplate. And your custom ComboBoxItem can be rendered without the DataTemplate.

So the first question is, is the DataTemplate even applied? (Just change the background of DataTemplates' grid and find that out, if it works).

Let's assume the DataTemplate actually works, what I would try:

{Binding Path=Image, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type SB:SBComboBoxItem}}

or RelativeSource as TemplatedParent with Content.Image

Comment: Yes, the DataTemplate works. DataTemplate functions very similarly to ControlTemplate (they both inherit from FrameworkTemplate), and is used for some templating where a ControlTemplate would not be appropriate (such as the templates used by ContentPresenters). If you set the datatemplate of a contentpresenter to an empty datatemplate, it will show nothing, no matter what the contentpresenter's other properties are set to.

Comment: To that end, my datatemplate works, as evidenced by the fact that it properly displays the SBComboBoxItem's content as text. Also, your binding resolution effectively equates to the same endpoint as the one I am already using, and it did not work.

Comment: Fair enough. When you use Text={Binding}, it shows that it binds against SBComboBoxItem, right? Everything seems ok. Let's see the actual dependency property implementation and the value that you assign it.

Comment: updated for that stuff in the main post. And yes, as far as I can tell, {Binding} works the same as explicitly binding to the Content property.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, on the DataTemplate part, you have to bind against Image's Source property, not against Image itself.

Like so:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.Resources>
    <BitmapImage x:Key="validImg" UriSource="test.png" />

    <DataTemplate  x:Key="TEMP" DataType="ComboBoxItem">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">

            <!--Not working Content(Image) is not valid for Source property I think-->
            <Image Source="{Binding Path=Content}" />
            <!--Working -->
            <Image Source="{Binding Path=Content.Source}" />
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Content}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <ContentPresenter 
        Content="{Binding Items[0], ElementName=test}"
        ContentTemplate="{StaticResource TEMP}">
    </ContentPresenter>

    <ComboBox x:Name="test" Height="50" Margin="0, 50, 0, 0">
        <ComboBoxItem >
            <ComboBoxItem.Content>
                <Image Source="{StaticResource validImg}" />
            </ComboBoxItem.Content>
        </ComboBoxItem>
    </ComboBox>
</Grid>
```